# Why my Data-Binding library does not working?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding

I'm trying to get datas from my class to my xml file so i tried to use data binding. But data-binding library does not working. When i write <data in my xml file, compiler does not shows anything. How can i solve this problem ? Otherwise how can i get datas from class to xml file without data binding ? Xml belongs to a fragment view.

```
   '''plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
    id 'kotlin-kapt'





}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cagataysencan.forumfisk_it"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            dataBinding true
        }

    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'


    //Navigation v Google Maps
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'

    // Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:2.3.1")
    testImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0")


    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.8.1"

    // RX Java
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    // Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0")
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1"

}**
```

Comment: "When i write <data in my xml file, compiler does not shows anything." - Are you attempting to generate xml at compile time?

Comment: No. I am not able to open tag like <data> </data> in xml file. That returns me an error : "Element data is not allowed here."

Comment: Can you show any code that indicates how you are attempting to generate xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
databinding {
    enabled=true
}
```

Also, remove viewBinding since there is no need for it if you are already using dataBinding..
Move  buildFeatures out of buildTypes so that it should be like this

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
    ...
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

And when you want to use dataBinding, make sure you enclose your layout with the `<layout>` tag to signify that the layout is eligible for dataBinding. So each xml file you want to bind should have the `<layout>` tag and can be like this for example:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <data>
        ...
   </data>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
...
...
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please match some line of plugin and dependency and version with kotlin and databinding in your gradle file that what you missing please check

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies{
   kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:4.0.0'
}


ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Hope it may help you